# Why both Jenkins and GitLab are not opening in browser when they are in the same server?

Tags: linux, git, nginx, jenkins, gitlab

On my Linux server, Jenkins was already installed, and I tried to install GitLab on same server, with following commands:

```
sudo yum install -y curl policycoreutils-python openssh-server cronie 
sudo lokkit -s http -s ssh
curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlab.fabcd.com" yum -y install gitlab-ee
```

It says that GitLab is now installed, but when i open the URL in browser, its not opening and also my Jenkins URL isn't working.

Please help me rollback this GitLab installation as I don't want to mess with my Jenkins.

Comment: Probably both exposed in port 8080

Comment: Yes, It looks like that only, any solution to this?

Comment: see my answer for this

Comment: @yorammi I tried this. When Jenkins stopped GitLab is can access via browser and when GitLab is stopped Jenkins can access via browser, but can't access both at the same time even Jenkins running at 8080 port and GitLab running at 80 port.

Comment: Wow - that was a year ago... Anyway, run 'netstat -a' to see what is on ports 80, 8080 and 8888

Answer (score 0):

Both servers exposed in port 8080.

You should change one of it to be different port.

To set the GitLab port, edit the file **/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
external_port "8888"
```

Then run reconfigure:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Comment: That did not work, any procedure to totally uninstall GITLAB and run only Jenkins like it was running before

Comment: Did you restart both Jenkins and GitLab after performing this?

Comment: So the problem is not with the port only. Anything you find in the log files of both services?

Comment: Also, GitLab address should be with port 8888 now, so did you browse to the new address?

Comment: Yes Gitlab with 8888

But now i wish to totally ignore GITLAB and repair my Jenkins, what can be checked?

*Jun 25, 2015 2:05:06 PM hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer tryReconnect*

I see such errors

Comment: the port is set in the jenkins.xml or config.xml file. And you should look at the log file as well.